# In Cocoa, do I have to do my own scaling in drawRect: if I choose to do custom pagination during printing?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, printing

The automatic pagination works fine with the scaling factor I set into the NSPrintInfo object. But then I switch to implementing my own pagination scheme.

Yes, I used the scaling factor to calculate rects covering the whole view, but the scaling factor seems not honored in the output automatically as seen in the automatic pagination.

So... does it mean that I have to my own scaling in my drawRect: to honor the scaling factor in NSPrintInfo during printing?

Answer (score 0):

No. Just make sure you match the [paperSize](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPrintInfo_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [imageablePageBounds](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPrintInfo_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: you should explain more on that. What do you mean by "match"? match where? when?